# Proof by Induction (n=k+1 steps difficulty)

Tags: induction

Use mathematical induction to prove that 
$(
1
−
a
)
^
n
>
1
−
na$
 for 
$\{
n
:
n
∈
Z
+
,
n
⩾
2
\}$
 where 
$0
<
a
<
1$
.

I understand the first steps but I don't understand the final ones (the $n = k+1$ steps). Please help me out if possible.

Comment: Please show your attempt

Answer (score 1):

Using induction hypothesis we have for $k+1$: $(1-a)^{k+1}=(1-a)^k \cdot (1-a)> (1-ka)(1-a)=1-a-ka+ka^2>1-a(k+1)$

Comment: You lost me on the least equality...what happened there?

Comment: @AndreaPettenello: $-a-ka=-(a+ka)=-a(1+k)$ and $ka^2$ is a positive number (something plus a positive number is greater than something)

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(n) = (1- a)^n, 0<a<1$

For $n = 2, P(2) = (1-a)^2 = 1- 2a + a^2 > 1 -2a$

Thus P(2) is true.

Let's assume P(n) is true for some n = k($\epsilon$Z)

So,$$P(k) = (1 - a)^k > 1- ka ---(i)$$
Now we have to prove P(k+1) is true.
$$i.e, P(k+1) = (1- a)^{k+1} > 1-(k+1)a ---(ii)$$
From inequality(i),$$LHS = P(k+1) = (1-a)^{k+1} = (1-a)^k.(1-a) > (1-ka).(1-a)$$
$$LHS>(1 - a - ka - a^2)$$ $$ LHS>(1-a(k+1) -a^2)$$ As $ 0<a<1, LHS>(1-(k+1)a).$
Hence Proved!!!